# Rails Token Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, token

I am building a Rails App where Users are supposed to be able to create a Tokens. The token is then used to insert data into the system for example with an embedded system. Then the user can look at a graph of the collected data.

Since Token Authentication in Devise is deprecated I sort of have to do my own thing.

My plan was to generate the token with SecureRandom.hex and save a sha1 hash of that token and display the token to the user once when creating it. And also add an expiration date that is renewed for two more weeks when it is being used.

The system collecting the data would then have to send the username and token with every request to the api.

Since I am using Devise for authentication but don't want to require sessions when using the api I was thinking of checking the username and token in the authenticate_user! method, however I am unsure if that is the way its done.

So my question is, would I do it that way? If not what should I rather do? Or are there any other concerns about the setup I explained?